# Css Slide Content

Tags: css, animation, push, slide

I am trying to achieve a push up content via css. I got the basic code from a slide menu tutorial and most of it works well.

But my "slide menu" goes all the way up to the top of the page when triggered, but I want it to only slide up 80% of the screen size, and I should only be this high itself. Tried alot but just can't figure it out.

**HTML**

```
<body>

<div id="container">
  <input id="toggle" type="checkbox"><label for="toggle">&equiv;</label>

  <div class="content"> content</div>

  <div class="slide-menu"> </div>

</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}

body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}

#container {
   display: flex;
   min-height: 100%;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
   position: absolute;
   opacity: 0;
}

label {
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   left: 40px;
   z-index: 1;
   display: block;
   font-size:3em;
   color: #444;
   cursor: pointer;
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   transition: transform .4s;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label {
   transform: translate3d(50px, 0, 0) rotate(0deg);
}

.content {
   width:100%;
   padding: 40px;
   background: #00FFA3;
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   transition: transform .4s;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .content {
   transform: translate3d(0, -250px, 0);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .slide-menu {
   transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0);
}

.slide-menu {
   transform: translate3d(0, 120%, 0);
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   background: #4f6b81;
   color: #ddd;
   left: 0;
   height: 80%;
   transition: all .4s;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this:

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k33x112p/)

I added `top: 20%` to the following css rule

```
.slide-menu {
   transform: translate3d(0, 120%, 0);
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   background: #4f6b81;
   color: #ddd;
   left: 0;
   top: 20%;
   height: 80%;
   transition: all .4s;
}
```